How to convert string to boolean value?
Is it possible to convert/wrap an array value into a if statement? For clarification, the statement I received from my code is always a string in an array, and I want to execute it in an if block. Right now, it does not do a comparison because it is a string. So how can I convert a string into a statement that will be compared?
let counter = 11;
let statement = ['counter > 10']; // array string received from other code (always a string)

if(statement[0]) {
    // should be true
}

Result expected to be true, where the if statement is dynamically executed.
EDIT: I found an answer by Using Function:
Execute JavaScript code stored as a string

Having an array does not matter for your question. Your question is "how can I evaluate a string as if it were JavaScript code?". Now, WHY do you want to do that? How do you intend to handle malicious input?

That is true. The array values are hard coded and the user cannot change it.

what you want to do is use an interpreter in the JS interpreter. What is the next step, put another interpreter in this interpreter added to the javascript interpreter?

Other answers and comments has mentioned

eval - obviously the most dangerous
new Function - easy to pollute global scope
mathematics parsers - good for simple expression

If you really want to execute any code, isolated-vm may help. (only in Node.js)
Also, when using isolated-vm, restricting the permission of the process is a must.

You may be able to use the math parser for this, though I'm not sure.  It'll depend on what kind of things you get back in that string.
// https://github.com/silentmatt/expr-eval/tree/master
// there may be other ways to do this, this is simple though
import Parser from 'expr-eval'; 

const options = {x:3};   //see the documentation

const parsedStatement = statement[0];
const result = Parser.evaluate(parsedStatement, {options});
console.debug('Expression Result: ', result);


I think a better way to ask this question is "How to evaluate a string as if it were Javascript code. There is a way to do it in JavaScript using the eval method.
let counter = 11;
let statement = ['counter > 10']; // (always a string)

if (eval(statement[0])) {
      // should be true
}

However, I would really not recommend using this. It's a huge security risk. Please use it only if you know what you are doing.
Referehce: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

Thanks, I found out another way by creating a New Function, that seems to work and a bit safer than eval. But it was the best answer so far.

let counter = 11;
let statement = ['counter > 10']; // (always a string)

if (eval(statement[0])) {
    console.log("The statement is true");
} else {
    console.log("The statement is false");
}


Is it only possible with eval?

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  While this answer may be technically correct (the best kind of correct), it is often helpful for the OP and future readers to provide context and an explanation rather than just code.
